# how to set the scr property of embed or object tag in code behind in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, flash

```
<object width="425" height="344">
    <embed src="PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="344"></embed>
</object>
```

how to set the scr property of embed or object tag in code behind in asp.net

Comment: yes i tried but the embed that is not available in visual studio 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a public property in code behind `.cs` file

```
public string EmbedSrc
{
    get; set;
}
```

set it in `Page_Load`

```
EmbedSrc = "PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE";
```

Then use the property in your asp.net markup code.

```
<object width="425" height="344">
    <embed src="<%= EmbedSrc %>" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="344"></embed>
</object>
```

**Edit: ** due to comments

You can make use of literal control

Place a literal control in markup code

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litEmbedObject"></asp:Literal>
```

Then set the text in `Page_Load`

```
litEmbedObject.Text = string.Format("<object width=\"425\" height=\"344\">" +
    "<embed src=\"{0}\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"425\" height=\"344\"></embed></object>", "PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE");
```

Comment: @waqas, how about making it runtat=server

Comment: @kobe, may be it work, but I would not recomend it. literal control will be better to use than making it `runat='server'`

Comment: do u mean i should use like <embed src=<%=Literal1%> type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="344"></embed>

Comment: you can replace whole object tag with literal control

Comment: oops, it is `string.Format` instead of stringFormat

Answer (score 0):

I found that the code below worked well with my ASP.Net application.
`<embed src="C://YOURFOLDER/YOURFILE" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="344"/>`

Mutantsfox